# Odoo 8 cannot backup database (postgres)

Tags: database, postgresql, backup, odoo-8

Whenever I try to backup my database, I get following error:

> Postgres subprocess ('/usr/bin/pg_dump', '--no-owner',
>   '--username=odoo', '--file=/tmp/tmp3AYPgp/dump.sql', u'OdooSetup')
>   error 1

Can someone help pls.

Comment: Could you please specify how are you trying to backup your database?

Comment: have u try from Administrator account ( super user) in odoo-8

Comment: @MarcoAltieri Through the Odoo /web/databases/manager and then backup (zip-file).

Answer (score 1):

Launch the command from system shell, there you'll see the error. f.e.:

pg_dump --no-owner --username=odoo OdooSetup >/dev/null

Answer (score 1):

I've just experienced this situation and in my case the problem was that there were some sequences in the database whose owner was not the expected one (it should be the same as the database owner).

I mean, my database is owned by PostgreSQL user `odoo`. But in this database, there were some sequences whose owner was `odoo_8` (who is another PostgreSQL user I have). I don't know the reason of why this happened, but you can fix that following the next steps:

Connect to your database through `psql`:

```
\c your_database
```

Show the owner of every table and sequence of your database:

```
\d
```

Check if there are some whose owner is not the right one. If so, change them:

```
ALTER SEQUENCE sequence_name OWNER TO right_user;
ALTER TABLE table_name OWNER TO right_user;
```

This command should also work and be much faster:

```
REASSIGN OWNED BY right_user TO right_user;
```

It should modify the owner of **all the databases** owner by `right_user`,  and all the tables and all the sequences of the **database you're connected to**.

In summary, if the database which gives you the error is named *my_database* and its PostgreSQL owner is `odoo`, connect to `psql` with the `odoo` user (or a superuser) and do this:

```
\c my_database
REASSIGN OWNED BY odoo TO odoo;
```

I hope this helps to someone.

Answer (score 0):

Give me some more details of this Error, i think at last it shows like No User odoo Found in the database like that.

First, check user odoo present in the database or not, if your system user name is odoo
Other wise create a Superuser in postgres using the same name as System user and try.